# Overriding a MIME type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mime, mime-types

I want to override the JSON MIME type ("application/json") in Rails to ("text/x-json").  I tried to register the MIME type again in mime_types.rb but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work (in an initializer, plugin, or some similar place):

```
Mime.send(:remove_const, :JSON)
Mime::Type.register "text/x-json", :json
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
render :json => var_containing_my_json, :content_type => 'text/x-json'
```