# Which JSON content type do I use?

Tags: json, mime-types, content-type

There are many "standards" for the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) content type:

```
application/json
application/x-javascript
text/javascript
text/x-javascript
text/x-json
```

Which one do I use, and where? I assume security and browser support issues are a factor.

Related: [What MIME type if JSON is being returned by a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404470/what-mime-type-if-json-is-being-returned-by-a-rest-api)

Answer (score 11532, accepted):

For JSON text:

```
application/json
```

> The MIME media type for JSON text is `application/json`. The default encoding is UTF-8. <sup>(Source: [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt))</sup>

For [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (runnable JavaScript) with callback:

```
application/javascript
```

Here are some blog posts that were mentioned in the relevant comments:

- [Why you shouldn't use `text/html` for JSON](http://jibbering.com/blog/?p=514)
- [Internet Explorer sometimes has issues with `application/json`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180102070201/www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/06/06/problems-with-internet-explorer-and-applicationjson/)
- [A rather complete list of Mimetypes and what to use them for](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types)
- [The official mime type list at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/) from @gnrfan's answer below

Comment: [Complete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

Comment: does it really matter what mime type it has? it's text that gets parsed into an object. wouldn't it be more natural to pass it as text/plain if you want it to be openable in browser without force download, and application/octet-stream if you want it to be automatically downloaded(useful if you're generating it on a webpage intended to be saved locally). Is there really that many people that will need to know the mime type so the downloader can view it with a special json viewer? What am I missing that warrants it a special mime type?

Comment: Using "text/plain" is a bad practice in general. There are, for instance, attacks in the web platform that would allow cross-origin data theft if you fail to send an appropriate MIME type value.

Comment: Internet Explorer sometimes has issues with application/json - blog is offline

Comment: Imagine I have a document written by somebody which contains plain text. Now that plain text just happens to be valid JSON as well. Would I then be wrong to use text/plain as its mime-type? JSON is a SUB-TYPE of text. So I think both should be allowed. The question is which works better in practice. According to comment by codetoshare IE has problems with application/json.  But no browser should have problems with text/plain. If text/plain is unsafe then how can I serve text-files from my web-site?

Comment: @EugenMihailescu The title of that page is "Incomplete list of MIME types"

Comment: Note that [RFC4627](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627) was obsoleted by [RFC7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159), itself replaced by [RFC8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259). The information provided here still holds.

Comment: @Omegastick True, however that page *does* have a link to the IANA list of "all" types linked in the answer.

Comment: Which are now called [Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) by the IANA.

Comment: The IETF has once gone around in another circle and is no longer recommending `application/javascript` as of [RFC 9239](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9239#name-iana-considerations)

Comment: Also interested in the correct file extension but I'm getting the impression it's `json` not `js` but I'd just like a standards reference for that... I've found it here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627 in RFC4627 specifying `json`. D. Crockford, json.org July 2006

Comment: I also wanted a standards defined file extension which I found: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627 in RFC4627 specifying `json`. D. Crockford, json.org July 2006. That's repeated in RFC 7159 and RFC 8259. It's listed in Section 11 "IANA Considerations".

Answer (score 1809):

[IANA](http://www.iana.org) has registered the official MIME Type for JSON as **`application/json`**.

When asked about why not `text/json`, Crockford seems to have said JSON is not really JavaScript nor text and also IANA was more likely to hand out `application/*` than `text/*`.

More resources:

- [Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/)
- [Request for Comments 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)
- [bluesmoon: JSON has a type](http://bluesmoon.livejournal.com/227190.html)

Comment: A lot of stuff got put into the `text/*` section in the early days that would probably be put into the `application/*` section these days.

Comment: @Rohmer - You "can" open anything in a text editor, but a binary format like JPEG or a Windows .exe or a .zip will contain non-printable characters which can actually break many text editors or cause undesired behavior. Try running `cat file.jpg` for example. Whereas any xml or json file is 100% printable. So I think Stijn de Witt's point is a valid one, despite the fact that yes, it's too late to change now.

Comment: @XP84 You can open any binary with a text editor in HEX form. And all the different characters (the 16 of them) are 100% printable. So, by that logic... *are all binaries text?* **Json is not text.** Json is *(warning: informal loose definition ahead)* a text representation of an object (or array of objects)

Comment: There is no meaning to the phrase "a text editor in HEX form". A Hex editor shows each byte as its hexadecimal value, for example, the byte 1111000 as "78". While there may be some text editors which also happen to have a hex editing mode, this is neither common nor useful for anything but the most technical users doing the most technical tasks. Text, by comparison, means ASCII or Unicode, and in text, the byte 1111000 means lower-case `x` character. Not 78. JSON is text in exactly the same way as HTML (text/html). It contains only readable text characters, with structured meaning in them.

Comment: I tend to agree with Stijn de Witt. JSON is meant to be viewed and edited with a text-editor.

Answer (score 1026):

**For JSON:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

**For [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):**

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: JSONP is not really JSON though, it's a technique for passing a JavaScript object literal

Answer (score 699):

Of course, the correct MIME media type for JSON is `application/json`, but it's necessary to realize what type of data is expected in your application.

For example, I use Java [Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/) and the server response must go as **text/html** but contains JSON data.

*Client side, Ext GWT form listener*

```java
uploadForm.getForm().addListener(new FormListenerAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void onActionFailed(Form form, int httpStatus, String responseText) 
    {
        MessageBox.alert("Error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionComplete(Form form, int httpStatus, String responseText) 
    {
        MessageBox.alert("Success");
    }
});
```

In case of using **application/json** response type, the browser suggests me to save the file.

*Server side source code snippet using [Spring MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Model-view-controller_framework)*

```java
return new AbstractUrlBasedView() 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map model, HttpServletRequest request,
                                           HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
};
```

Comment: server response must go as text/html. This is true for the ExtJS variant as well.

Answer (score 517):

### **JSON:**

Response is dynamically generated data, according to the query parameters passed in the URL.

**Example:**

```
{ "Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7 }
```

**Content-Type:** `application/json`

---

### **JSON-P:**

JSON with padding.
Response is JSON data, with a function call wrapped around it.

**Example:**

```
functionCall({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

**Content-Type:** `application/javascript`

Comment: The definition of JSON is wrong. It does not need to be dynamically generated or respect query parameters. You can serve a static JSON file. Also, the most upvoted answer has a link to the RFC.

Comment: Also JSONP can be json data assigned to a var.

Answer (score 438):

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian and you serve .json files through Apache, you might want to serve the files with the correct content type. I am doing this primarily because I want to use the Firefox extension [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869/)

The Apache module [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) will help to do this easily. However, with Ubuntu you need to edit the file */etc/mime.types* and add the line

```
application/json json
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: usually a reload is enough (faster than restart). Also, note that you can now do "sudo service apache2 reload".

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has this by default

Answer (score 417):

If you're calling ASP.NET Web Services from the client-side you have to use `application/json` for it to work. I believe this is the same for the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29) frameworks.

Comment: jQuery seems to work with at least  'application/json' and 'text/plain'... I haven't tried all the others though.

Comment: jQuery is capable of working with `content-Type: text/plain`, `content-Type: application/json`, `content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`,  `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 332):

The right content type for JSON is `application/json` UNLESS you're using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), also known as JSON with Padding, which is actually JavaScript and so the right content type would be `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 323):

There is no doubt that `application/json` is the best [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type for a JSON response.

But I had some experience where I had to use `application/x-javascript` because of some compression issues. My hosting environment is shared hosting with [GoDaddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy). They do not allow me to change server configurations. I had added the following code to my `web.config` file for compressing responses.

```
<httpCompression>
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

By using this, the .aspx pages was compressed with g-zip but JSON responses were not. I added

```
<add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
```

in the static and dynamic types sections. **But this does not compress JSON responses at all.**

After that I removed this newly added type and added

```
<add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
```

in both the static and dynamic types sections, and changed the response type in

.ashx (asynchronous handler) to

```
application/x-javascript
```

And now I found that my JSON responses were compressed with g-zip. So I personally recommend to use

```
application/x-javascript
```

only if you want to compress your JSON responses on a **shared hosting environment**. Because in shared hosting, they do not allow you to change [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) configurations.

Comment: "So I personally recommending to use application/x-javascript" is where this answer becomes misleading. GoDaddy *does* allow compression of `application/json`, I leverage it on my shared hosting and I wouldn't suggest using a different content type to enable compression anyway, it's simply wrong. It can be done, but it will still be wrong. Using different content types for *browser support* is one thing, using different content types for server-side compression is another.

Answer (score 285):

Only when using `application/json` as the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type I have the following (as of November 2011 with the most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29)):

- No more warnings from Chrome when the JSON is loaded from the server.
- Firebug will add a tab to the response showing you the JSON data
  formatted. If the MIME type is different, it will just show up as
  'Response content'.

Answer (score 268):

Not everything works for content type `application/json`.

If you are using [Ext JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) form submit to upload file, be aware that the server response is parsed by the browser to create the document for the `<iframe>`.

If the server is using JSON to send the return object, then the `Content-Type` header must be set to `text/html` in order to tell the browser to insert the text unchanged into the document body.

See [the Ext JS 3.4.0 API documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/index.html).

Comment: Tools that don't adhere to standards should be avoided whenever possible; use `application/json` per spec.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer while that is true, it's not specific to ExtJs per se. It's a browser limitation (or rather, perhaps, a "security measure").

Comment: Surely it would be better to use text/plain so it doesn't apply any HTML semantics to non-HTML content? Or don't browsers let you extract a frame's content if it's got no DOM?

Comment: To add further confusion: I'm just debugging a similar case on Samsung Galaxy Beam (Android 2.3) with default browser, and the `iframe` seems to fire `load` event for `application/javascript`, `application/x-javascript`, `text/javascript`, `text/plain`, but **NOT** firing it for `application/json` nor `text/html`. As of today, Android <=2.3 is About 50% of the Android market share.

Answer (score 243):

JSON is a [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (DSL) and a data format independent of JavaScript, and as such has its own [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type, `application/json`. Respect for MIME types is of course client driven, so `text/plain` may do for transfer of bytes, but then you would be pushing up interpretation to the vendor application domain unnecessarily - `application/json`. Would you transfer XML via `text/plain`?

But honestly, your choice of MIME type is advice to the client as to how to interpret the data- `text/plain` or `text/HTML` (when it's not HTML) is like type erasure- it's as uninformative as making all your objects of type Object in a typed language.

No browser runtime I know of will take a JSON document and automatically make it available to the runtime as a JavaScript accessible object without intervention, but if you are working with a crippled client, that's an entirely different matter. But that's not the whole story- [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) JSON services often don't have JavaScript runtimes, but it doesn't stop them using JSON as a viable data interchange format. If clients are that crippled... then I would consider perhaps HTML injection via an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) templating service instead.

Application/JSON!

Answer (score 224):

If you're in a client-side environment, investigating about the cross-browser support is mandatory for a well supported web application.

The right HTTP Content-Type would be `application/json`, as others already highlighted too, but some clients do not handle it very well, that's why jQuery recommends the default `text/html`.

Answer (score 189):

The correct answer is:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 183):

As many others have mentioned, `application/json` is the correct answer.

But what haven't been explained yet is what the other options you proposed mean.

- `application/x-javascript`: Experimental MIME type for JavaScript before `application/javascript` was made standard.
- `text/javascript`: Now obsolete. You should use `application/javascript` when using javascript.
- `text/x-javascript`: Experimental MIME type for the above situation.
- `text/x-json`: Experimental MIME type for JSON before `application/json` got officially registered.

All in all, whenever you have any doubts about content types, you should check [this link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: When did `text/javascript` become obsolete? I'm still filling up HTML documents with `<script type="text/javascript" ...` tags.

Comment: It makes no difference for browsers, really. It's just obsolete for RFC standards: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt

Comment: @Oli you can safely drop `type="text/javascript"` and just do `<script>...</script>` at least according to HTML5.

Answer (score 164):

In [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), you can use this in page directive:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

The correct [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) media type for JSON is `application/json`.  JSP will use it for sending a response to the client.

Answer (score 127):

“`application/json`” is the correct JSON content type.

```
def ajaxFindSystems = {
  def result = Systems.list()
  render(contentType:'application/json') {
    results {
      result.each{sys->
        system(id:sys.id, name:sys.name)
      }
    }
    resultset (rows:result.size())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 126):

The [IANA registration for `application/json`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json) says

> Applications that use this media type:  JSON has been used to
>      exchange data between applications written in all of these
>      programming languages: ActionScript, C, C#, Clojure, ColdFusion,
>      Common Lisp, E, Erlang, Go, Java, JavaScript, Lua, Objective CAML,
>      Perl, PHP, Python, Rebol, Ruby, Scala, and Scheme.

You'll notice that IANA.org [doesn't list any of these other media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), in fact even `application/javascript` is now obsolete. So `application/json` is really the only possible *correct* answer.

Browser support is another thing.

The most widely supported non-standard media types are `text/json` or `text/javascript`. But some big names even use `text/plain`.

Even more strange is the Content-Type header sent by Flickr, who returns JSON as `text/xml`. Google uses `text/javascript` for some of it's ajax apis.

Examples:

```
curl -I "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/video?v=1.0&q=jsonexample"
```

Output: `Content-Type: text/javascript`

```
curl -I "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&api_key=f82254c1491d894f1204d8408f645a93"
```

Output: `Content-Type: text/xml`

Answer (score 98):

The right MIME type is **`application/json`**

**BUT**

I experienced many situations where the browser type or the framework user needed:

```
text/html

application/javascript
```

Comment: Example of such a situation?

Answer (score 82):

I use the below

```
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(SendData),
```

Answer (score 72):

The **Content-Type** header should be set to '**application/json**' when posting. Server listening for the request should include "**Accept=application/json**".
In Spring MVC you can do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="location", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

Add headers to the response:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 65):

> The `application/json` works great in PHP to store an array or object
>   data.

I use this code to put data in JSON on [*Google Cloud Storage (GCS)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738814/4058484) which is set [publically viewable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866924/4058484):

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'gs' => [
        'acl'=>'public-read', 
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]
]);

file_put_contents(
    "gs://BUCKETNAME/FILENAME.json", 
    json_encode((object) $array), 
    false, 
    $context
);
```

To get back the data is straight forward:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("gs://BUCKETNAME/FILENAME.json"));
```

Answer (score 65):

- `Content-Type: application/json` - JSON
- `Content-Type: application/javascript` - [JSON-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- `Content-Type: application/x-javascript` - JavaScript
- `Content-Type: text/javascript` - JavaScript *but* obsolete. Older Internet Explorer versions used to use it for HTML attributes.
- `Content-Type: text/x-javascript` - JavaScript Media Types, *but* obsolete
- `Content-Type: text/x-json` - JSON before *application/json* got officially registered.

Comment: For JSON text:
    application/json

   Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 63):

In [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) you have a defined type: `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` which is equivalent to *application/json*.

Comment: That's Java EE too :: [javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON)

Answer (score 58):

For JSON, I am using:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

This is described in the IETF's JSON Data Interchange Format 7158 proposal, [Section 1.2: Specifications of JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7158#section-1.2).

Answer (score 55):

If the JSON is with padding then it will be `application/jsonp`. If the JSON is without padding then it will be `application/json`.

To deal with both, it is a good practice to use: 'application/javascript' without bothering whether it is with padding or without padding.

Comment: The first part of your answer is wrong. "application/jsonp" is not a valid MIME type. The response body of a JSONP is just JavaScript, so one of the MIME-types for JavaScript has to be used.

Answer (score 50):

Extending the accepted responses, when you are using JSON in a REST context...

There is a [strong argument](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#content-types) about using `application/x-resource+json` and `application/x-collection+json` when you are representing REST resources and collections.

And if you decide to follow the **jsonapi** specification, [you should](http://jsonapi.org/format/#content-negotiation) use of `application/vnd.api+json`, as it is documented.

Altough there is not an universal standard, it is clear that the added semantic to the resources being transfered justify a more explicit *Content-Type* than just `application/json`.

Following this reasoning, other contexts could justify a more specific *Content-Type*.

Comment: `application/vnd.api+json` seems to be specifically for apis using [json:api](http://jsonapi.org/), a very narrow specification with its own expectations and format, I don't understand it to be for *any* API that returns json. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 49):

PHP developers use this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    // Do something here...
?>
```

Answer (score 49):

If you get data from REST API in JSON, you have to use *[Content-Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type)*:

- For JSON data: *Content-Type:application/json*
- For HTML data: *Content-Type:text/html*,
- For XHTML data: *Content-Type:application/xhtml+xml*,
- For XML data: *Content-Type:text/xml, application/xml*

Answer (score 36):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (JavaScript Object Notation) and [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) ("JSON with padding") formats seems to be very similar and therefore it might be very confusing which MIME type they should be using. Even though the formats are similar, there are some subtle differences between them.

So whenever in any doubts, I have a very simple approach (which works perfectly fine in most cases), namely, go and check corresponding RFC document.

**JSON**
[RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) (The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)) is a specifications of JSON format. It says in section 6, that the MIME media type for JSON text is

```
application/json.
```

**JSONP**
JSONP ("JSON with padding") is handled different way than JSON, in a browser. JSONP is treated as a regular JavaScript script and therefore it should use `application/javascript,` the current official MIME type for JavaScript. In many cases, however, `text/javascript` MIME type will work fine too.

Note that `text/javascript` has been marked as obsolete by [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) (Scripting Media Types) document and it is recommended to use `application/javascript` type instead. However, due to legacy reasons, `text/javascript` is still widely used and it has cross-browser support (which is not always a case with `application/javascript` MIME type, especially with older browsers).

Answer (score 21):

The most common [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) is application/json. Here is a list of all JSON content types:

- `Content-Type: application/json` - [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
- `Content-Type: text/x-json` - JSON before *application/json* got officially registered.
- `Content-Type: application/javascript` - [JSON-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- `Content-Type: application/x-javascript` - JavaScript

**Obsolete Types:**

- `Content-Type: text/javascript` - JavaScript *but* obsolete. Older Internet Explorer versions used to use it for HTML attributes.
- `Content-Type: text/x-javascript` - JavaScript Media Types, *but* obsolete

**Additional References:**

[RFC4627](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627) -  The `application/json` Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Comment: Out of curiosity - when did application/json officially get registered ? I have a URL endpoint that outputs JSON, but in text format and not sending a Content-Type: application/json header.

Comment: hi @anjanesh! these references should be helpful:  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627 and  https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json

Answer (score 15):

To complement the previous the answers, the MIME type for JSON linked data (JSON-LD) [according to W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-syntax/#iana-considerations) is:

> `application/ld+json`
>
> **Type name:** application
>
> **Subtype name:** ld+json

Additionally, from the same source:

> **File extension(s)**:
>
> `.jsonld`

Answer (score 15):

As you may have to use these more frequently, always try to remember these three content types even though there are [many content types](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types):

- Content-Type: application/json
- Content-Type: application/xml
- Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Don't forget `text/plain`

Answer (score 14):

For specifying the interesting JSON result, you add "application/json" in your request header like below:

"Accept:application/json" is a desired response format.

"Content-Type:application/json" specifies the content format of your request, but sometimes you specify both `application/json` and `application/xml`, but the quality of these might be different. Which server will send back the different response formats, look at the example:

```
Accept:application/json;q=0.4,application/xml;q=8
```

This will return XML, because XML has higher quality.

Comment: If I may start an argument here: The accept header in the request does not make the server reply in that format. As you said, it's the desired format. The q qualifier is a wieghtage. The server app can go ahead and reply in whatever format it desires if it doesn't do as the request says. Along the same vein, if the server app only supports xml, specifying json won't do any auto-convert; you'll get an xml response.

Answer (score 14):

The proper current standard is `application/json`. While the default encoding is UTF-8, it is worth mentioning that it could also be UTF-16 or UTF-32. When JSON is written in UTF-16 or UTF-32, binary content-transfer-encoding must be used.

There is more information about JSON in *[RFC 4627: The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)*

More information on binary transfer encoding is on *[5. The Content-Transfer-Encoding Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html)* (RFC 1341).

Answer (score 10):

As some research,

The most common MIME type is

**application/json**

Let's see a example to differentiate with JSON and JavaScript.

- application/json

It is used when it is not known how this data will be used. When the information is to be just extracted from the server in JSON format, it may be through a link or from any file, in that case, it is used.

For example-

```
<?php

    header('Content-type:application/json');

    $directory = [
            ['Id' => 1, 'Name' => 'this'],
            ['Id' => 2, 'Name' => 'is'],
            ['Id' => 3, 'Name' => 'Stack Overflow'],
        ];

    // Showing the JSON data

    echo json_encode($directory);
?>
```

The output is,

```
[{"Id":1, "Name":"this"}, {"Id":2, "Name":"is"}, {"Id":3, "Name":"Stack Overflow"}]
```

---

- application/javascript

It is used when the use of the data is predefined. It is used by applications in which there are calls by the client-side Ajax applications. It is used when the data is of type JSON-P or [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

For example

```
<?php

    header('Content-type:application/javascript');

    $dir = [
            ['Id' => 1, 'Name' => 'this' ],
            ['Id' => 2, 'Name' => 'is'],
            ['Id' => 3, 'Name' => 'Stack Overflow'],
    ];

    echo "Function_call(" . json_encode($dir) . ");";
?>
```

The output is,

```
Function_call([{"Id":1, "Name":"this"}, {"Id":2, "Name":"is"}, {"Id":3, "Name":"Stack Overflow"}])
```

And for other MIME types, see the full detail in *[MIME types (IANA media types)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)*.

Comment: What is the difference between JSON-P or JSONP?

Comment: Visit to this page,for JSON-P vs JSONP difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp

Answer (score 8):

A part of your question is relevant to me as I just came across it.

A third-party provider is providing a REST service that is used by multiple clients. It's a straight-forward REST called with query parameters that returns a well-formed JSON. I have tested it with PHP and Java where it worked as expected.

My client uses Oracle Service Bus as a gateway between his application server and the Internet. When I made the OSB service, it crashed with an `Invalid message format` error. Turned out that the `content-type` being returned was `text/html`. OSB treats responses as per this header; converting between text, XML and JSON. In this case, the response was JSON but the header didn't say so. Contacting the provider, I got the reply: "We're not going to change it as it doesn't effect anyone else".

The `Content-Type` header specifies what the content **should** be, not what it **actually** is. That is to say, in your consuming program, it's up to you to check or ignore it and process the content in any manner. Another example, you can return GIF data but specify the content type as JSON, then go ahead and ignore the header and read the image data. This won't hurt your program, but may hurt others.

Moral of the story: Play nice.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the point of view.

If you are the client sending a request, then `application/json` is the right choice.

But if you are the server receiving a request, you have to be prepared, that the client may also send the encoding. So `application/json` and `application/json; charset=utf-8` are valid.

The media type is the same in both cases. But the content type differs.

Answer (score 0):

The standard and widely accepted JSON content type to use is:

> application/json

You should use it because:

- the content type for transmitting JSON data in HTTP requests and responses.
- It is the official MIME type for JSON data and is supported by all modern browsers and web servers.

**Other are obselete:**

The other content types user mentioned (application/x-javascript, text/javascript, text/x-javascript, text/x-json) were used in the past when JSON was not as standardized as it is now. However, using them today is not recommended due to potential security and compatibility issues.

**Security Concerns:**

- Some older browsers may interpret JavaScript content types (application/x-javascript, text/javascript, text/x-javascript) as executable scripts, potentially leading to security vulnerabilities if an attacker injects malicious code.
- Serving JSON data with non-standard content types might trigger security mechanisms in certain browsers or web applications.

**Browser Support:**

- While modern browsers have largely standardized on application/json, some older browsers might not handle other content types correctly.
- *application/json* is supported by all major browsers and has become the de facto standard for JSON data.

Hope it helps.